# How to manage the cycle life on Xamarin Forms with PiP mode

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I’m developing a video app that supports PiP mode. The app is developed with Xamarin forms and the page where is the player I release resources and stop the video on the method “ondisappearing” but when app changes to PiP mode, this method is called and then app stops of playing.

I have been checking other methods in order to detect it… but I’m not finding the correct combination. One thing that I have though is to check the pressed back button but… when user tap the soft button isn’t executed this method. Next I have checked is the pause and resume event of “App” of Xamarin forms but this methods aren’t executed when app in/out of PIP mode. I may use this with some Boolean for example in order to detect the state of pause vs pip mode. But I can’t different from back navigation (or I don’t see how)

From Main activity of android I have seen that is executed the method of onPause and onResume when in/out PiP mode, but this method is executed later of launching onDisappearing event on player page, so app has unregistered events and I can't resume .

Are there some property on NavigationPage which I can detect if user is navigating or is in/out PiP mode? I would like release resources and stop player only when user navigate or change to other app. Thank you

Comment: My suggestion here is that you can create a `CustomRenderer` for the Page where the PIP is enabled that way you will be able to handle the Video Playback from there. If you need more info after this later I could help you with a sample code.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I’m using a custom render for the view of player… but what do you check on it?  I have been searching more information and I have found a possible method, `Activity.inPictureInPicture()` … I will try to check if when it is stopped, the app is on pip mode… I will tell you if I have got it.